# A tutorial on SQLite3 for Node.js and a code example explanation wanted

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, sqlite

I am a bit confused with SQLite at the moment, as this is the first time I'm ever using a database. I got sqlite3 from here: https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3.

I'm looking at that example there, some things I do understand, while others I do not. Most of those database commands that are wrapped in `.run()`, `.prepare()` and the like give me a hard time.

This is the example:

```
var usersDB = new sqlite3.Database("databases/users.db");

  usersDB.serialize(function() {
  usersDB.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

  var stmt = usersDB.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  usersDB.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
  });
});

usersDB.close();
```

Also, how do I store simple things such as usernames, passwords (do I have to hash them myself?) and emails in the SQLite database on Node.js?

Comment: Hello Bane, your question seems to be a little vague and bordering on using stackoverflow as your personal research machine. It also helps if you could tell us what you have tried and what went wrong. I also checked the link to the github repo and there seems to be a wiki and an example directory.

Comment: Well I'm basically asking for a tutorial aimed at newcommers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try [node-sqlite from grumdrig](https://github.com/grumdrig/node-sqlite). He has a [very nice "example-driven" documentation](http://grumdrig.com/node-sqlite).

Comment: The linked page has a link to an asynchronous API. [This one](https://github.com/orlandov/node-sqlite).

Comment: This might be more easy to do asynchronous things: npm install [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sqlite3) - Asynchronous, non-blocking SQLite3 binding. 2014-0307.

Answer (score 6):

There are two distinct things to learn: sqlite the database program, and node-sqlite3 the nodejs module that provides access to the sqlite db services. Your database questions will be best answered by learning about sqlite, the database program first.
I would recommend getting and installing sqlite from: http://www.sqlite.org/. The site has good documentation that will help you learn to store user names and passwords. You can create tables from the command line, add data and get as sense of what is going on. After that if you understand the concepts of node.js then  node-sqlite3 will make much more sense to you. Otherwise, spend some time with the node.js site.