# Nodejs - Multiple File or Single File Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The question explains itself. But which do you think is better?
Using a multiple file database or a single file database?

The data has to be accessed by multiple clients, which means
that it has to be robust in reading data. Which means that a single file
database will be much faster, but if something fails, my data can become
corrupted, and I don't want that. If I'll go for multiple file database,
I am worried about the file overhead. Which do you think is better? :)

Comment: use sqlite3, it's good file base database

[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040897/a-tutorial-on-sqlite3-for-node-js-and-a-code-example-explanation-wanted

Comment: If it is a requirement that multiple clients access the same file the same time you should a with a real database. sqlite is good for starters.

Answer (score 0):

use a single file database for nodejs with nginx